# How to connect GoogleSignIn authentication to user profile?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have 2 authentication methods in my app: 1) email (via `FirebaseAuth`), and 2) Google (`GoogleSignIn`).

With FirebaseAuth email authentication, I'm able to pull an automatically generated user id with `Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`. That user id is then associated with the email used to sign up/in. **Similarly, is there an automatically generated user id that I can pull for users who authenticate with `GoogleSignIn`?**

This is how I'm authenticating users with Google:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        
        if error == nil {
            
            // Create the user profile and store the user info
            UserService.createProfile(userId: "wantThisToBeAnAutoGeneratedId", firstName: "firstName", lastName: "lastName", email: user.profile.email) { (user) in
            }
        }
    }
```

Any support and guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Ask one question at a time, por favor.

Comment: Are you looking for `GIDGoogleUser#userid`? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDGoogleUser#userid

Comment: You can get an id named 'clientID' when a user successfully logs in with GoogleSignIn.

Comment: func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
 if let error = error {
  return
 }
     
 guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
 if let clientID = authentication.clientID {
  print("You are now logged in as : \(clientID)")
 }
}

Comment: @ElTomato Would that clientID be unique to every user that signs in with Google?

Comment: Sorry...  Actually, you can't use that.  That's YOUR id, I think.

Comment: You can use `userID`.  Don't ask me if each `userID` is unique.  I don't work for Google.  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
 if let error = error {
  print(error)
  return
 }
  
 guard let _ = user.authentication else { return }
 if let userID = user.userID {
  print("User ID: \(userID)")
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the credential. GoogleSignIn have been updated to version 6.0.2 so my function “didSignInFor
“ it is different than yours. For that reason I check for an optional value with guard but you can get the idea regardless.

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        
        // If sign in succeeded, display the app's main content View.
        guard let user = user else { return }
        let authentication = user.authentication
        if let token = authentication.idToken {
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: token, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
            FirebaseRef.shared.signinGoogleUser(credential, user) {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .googleSignInComplete, object: self, userInfo: nil)
            } onError: { (error) in
                let title = NSLocalizedString("alert_sorry", comment: "")
                let errorMessage = [title : error]
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .googleSignInError, object: self, userInfo: errorMessage)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I’m assuming your function UserService.createProfile
Is basically to get the user data just like my FirebaseRef.shared.signinGoogleUser

Below is how I use the function to populate the user data.

```
/// Gets data from Google Sign In Authentication. Checks if user exists, if so continues the App's navigation flow otherwise sends data to createUser function to write new user to database
/// - Parameters:
///   - credential: credential of type AuthCredential as Google
///   - user: GIDGoogleUser from Authentication
///   - onSuccess: Continues App's flow
///   - onError: Alerts user of issues
func signinGoogleUser(_ credential: AuthCredential, _ user: GIDGoogleUser, onSuccess: @escaping() -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
    auth.signIn(with: credential) { [self] (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("authentication error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard let result = authResult else { return }
        
        let docRef = documentSpecificUser(uid: result.user.uid)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist. Create user.")
                
                let id = result.user.uid
                let displayName = user.profile?.name ?? ""
                let firstName = user.profile?.givenName ?? ""
                let lastName = user.profile?.familyName ?? ""
                let email = user.profile?.email ?? ""
                let imageURL = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 400)?.absoluteString
                
                createUser(with: firstName, lastName, id, email: email, displayName, imageURL) {
                    onSuccess()
                } onError: { (error) in
                    onError(error)
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```